# CRM 2011: Retrieving shared appointments using SQL Query

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, reporting-services

There is a known limitation for Filtered Views in CRM 2011 for Activities.  The filtered views do not display shared records. Looks like this is fixed in Update Rollup 6, however our servers haven't been upgraded to UR 6 yet.

I currently have a custom report that retrieves appointments using FilteredAppointment view and it's only retrieving the user owned appointments.

**Is there anyway we can retrieve the shared appointments for the current user using the SQL query. Please help.**

Comment: the upgrade is totally out of discussion?

Comment: the upgrade is planned but will not happen until May I believe. So till then we would want to use a workaround in the report

Answer (score 0):

I believe shared records are stored in the PrincipalObjectAccess. However just joining to this table still won't quite work due to those records being removed out of the filtered views.  You will most likely have to join the activityid to the objectid in the PrincipalObjectAccess to either the native view or the actual tables themselves.

Another thing I would mention is if you are using Team ownership or teams at all then this would end up being more complicated because you would have to figure out which teams the user belongs to as well and see if the records are shared out to that team.